# OpenLayers map shows partial map on page load, unless dev-tools are opened

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I have a OpenLayers map with a few KML layers being added dynamically on top of it. On page load I see only a part of the map in top left corner of designated html div. I can't figure out the source of this issue. Neither of projection, zoom level seems or initial position is affecting the load.
It is strange that when I open the chrome dev-tools (or Inspector window for Firefox), map behaves exactly as expected and complete map is displayed.

Note: above issue is only found with base layer from Google such as "Google Streets" while with base layer such as OSM it works fine.

Browsers tested on:

- Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m
- Firefox 23.0.1
- Firefox 24.0

Comment: This is definitely a code issue. You need to share some of your code which shows this behavior.